# Having trouble with my GUI's templated widget system

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, user-interface, widget

I'm gonna post my code first then explain my issue:

```
    std::list<Widget::Ptr> m_widgets;

    std::list<Widget::Ptr>::iterator findObject(const std::string& id)
    {
        for (auto iter = m_widgets.begin(); iter != m_widgets.end(); ++iter)
        {
            if ((*iter)->getId() == id)
                return iter;
        }

        return m_widgets.end();
    }

    template <class T> void pushWidget(std::shared_ptr<T> widget)
    {
        auto iter = findObject(widget->getId());

        if (iter != m_widgets.end())
            return;

        m_widgets.push_back(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Widget>(widget));
    }

    template <class T> std::shared_ptr<T> getWidget(const std::string& id)
    {
        auto iter = findObject(id);

        if (iter != m_widgets.end())
            return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(*iter);

        return nullptr;
    }

    const std::type_index& getType(const std::string& id)
    {
        auto iter = findObject(id);

        if (iter != m_widgets.end())
            return typeid(*iter);
    }
```

Widget::Ptr is a typedef of std::shared_ptr just by the way. Anyways, the issue I'm having is how to tell getWidget() what type of widget the widget is. Widget is a base class that other widgets inherit from, such as Label, Editbox, etc. For my main GUI manager, I'm trying to shorten my code as much as I can to make updating/drawing as clean as possible. Now, Menu is a type of widget that I'm trying to use in this case:

```
auto type = SceneManager::getCurrentScene().m_gui.getType(widgetId);

SceneManager::getCurrentScene().m_gui.getWidget<typeid(type)>(widgetId)->attachToMenu(getId());
```

However, this isn't working and I'm getting these errors from my compiler:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'SE::GUI::getWidget(const string&)'|
note: candidate is:|
note: template<class T> std::shared_ptr<_Tp> SE::GUI::getWidget(const string&)|
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
```

I can provide any more details that are needed, and thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Don't use `std::list`, use `std::vector`. That could improve your performance. Actually, you mean `decltype(type)`, not `typeid(type)`

Answer (score 1):

`typeid(type)` doesn't return the type of an expression `type`, but runtime information about the type (RTTI). What you want is `decltype()`, which returns the type of an expression:

```
SceneManager::getCurrentScene().m_gui.getWidget<decltype(type)>(widgetId)->attachToMenu(getId());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately when I run this code I get this error: 'struct std::type_index' has no member named 'attachToMenu'